# Why is the 'Integrity' property required in consensus protocols?

Tags: distributed-systems, consensus

Formally a [consensus protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_(computer_science)) must satisfy the following three properties:

**Termination**

- Eventually, every correct process decides some value.

**Integrity**

- If all the correct processes proposed the same value "v", then any correct process must decide "v".

**Agreement**

- Every correct process must agree on the same value.

"Termination" certifies the protocol is resilient to halting failures. "Agreement" deters any two correct processes from deciding on different values which would break consensus. But what about "Integrity", why is it required? If all correct processes propose "x" but then they all decide "y" (e.g. `y = f(x)`), is that a violation of consensus?

Comment: It's just a definition, it depends on what you're trying to achieve. The wikipedia article considers this property necessary, but also mentions that depending on the application, it might me modified. If you don't need it, you can leave it our, but usually it's needed, so it's included.

Comment: I.e. it's not "logical" to have the integrity constraint, it's convention.

Comment: Without this requirement an algorithm always returning some constant would be a 'correct' consensus algorithm.

Comment: @orlp That makes sense. I was thinkig more about a function that transforms 'x' into 'y', not necessarily a constant function, but in that case I guess proposing 'x' would just be a proxy for proposing 'y', i.e., in practice probably not a violation of the integrity property.